# Lite version of iOS app with changes in scene (storyboard)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a lite version of my app. When I searched on google, almost all the solutions mentioned to create a duplicate target and set necessary flags (to differentiate between full and lite version).

Now I did the necessary things but in my lite app I want some controls in one scene to be disabled. So how do I do it in the design mode?

With the flag sets I can differentiate between full and lite app while Runtime. But can I make the changes to a scene only for lite app in Design Time?

Or for every scene load, I'll have to check the flag and then do the disable/enable code in runtime.

What are my options? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most manageable way is in your code. One example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (kIsLiteVersion) {
        [someObject setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Or, perhaps you'd do this in `init` in some cases (maybe you want to not create certain objects in the lite version). Or, maybe use the condition to determine which storyboard view controller to push in some cases, and have some for the lite version.

Comment: Yes I guess this is what I'll have to do. Thanks Anton for your help.